# Envers - MappedSuperclass attribute not found. @AuditMappedBy points to a property that doesn't exist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, audit, hibernate-envers

I am trying to add envers into my project but I have problems with the visibility of a MappedSuperclass attribute. The structure is like this:

A parent abstract class

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class Parent {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "joinedEntity_id")
  protected JoinedEntity field;
}
```

Two child classes that extend the parent class with @Audited annotation and @AuditOverride, both have the same structure:

```
@Audited
@AuditOverride(forClass = Parent.class, isAudited = true)
class Child extends Parent {

   Child{ super(...); }
}
```

And the joined entity like this:

```
public class JoinedEntity {

  @Singular
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "field", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  @AuditMappedBy(mappedBy = "field")
  private List<Child> childs;
}
```

And the error comes because from the JoinedEntity class it can't get resolve the AuditMappedBy that points to the abstract class attribute, even though I add the AuditOverride in the child class. Here is the error:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: @AuditMappedBy points to a property that doesn't exist: $path.Child.field

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is because you're using `@AuditMappedBy` to point a non-audited property.

If you take a look at your definition of `Child`, the `@AuditOverride` specifically states that for all properties that are declared in `Parent`, they are **not** audited.  So you have 3 options here.

1. Define the `field` property in the `Parent` class as being audited, whether you do that via the `@AuditOverride` annotation or specifically adding the `@Audited` annotation to the property in the `Parent` class should work.
2. Define the association in the `JoinedEntity` as the relation not being audited.  In other words, this causes the FK value to be audited but the relationship between them are not.  This means when you fetch revisions of `JoinedEntity`, the association is always loaded from the ORM main table.

   ```
   @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetMode.NOT_AUDITED)
   @AuditMappedBy(mappedBy = "field")
   ```
3. Remove the `@AuditMappedBy` since the `Parent` class `field` property is *not* audited.